# convert encoded html entities to utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, xss

How do I convert this string into UTF-8:

> &#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041

I want to also convert this one:

> &#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29

I want to prevent XSS attacks and I am using this article as a cheat sheet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

My strategy is to convert the above string to UTF-8 and check if it contains javascript.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Care to explain why?

Comment: How about using `htmlspecialchars()` when you output to the browser?

Comment: @jeroen Can you give more information on how to use it? I have tried it and the outcome is the same

Comment: _Why the downvotes?_ Because of no attempt..... Besides that, on SO we prefere questions that can be answered not just discussed..... _My strategy is..._ is not enough ;)

Comment: I am sorry if I communicated my question as a discussion, but I am pretty sure it has a straightforward answer. I have attempts but none of them worked, so I simply didn't include any.

Comment: that's simple, did you try something?

Comment: @JohnSmith you are 18 days late. the problem has been solved.

Comment: @rakipi ...and you still haven't tried something

Comment: @JohnSmith actually, I came up with the solution because even the accepted answer didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you post the solution then?

Comment: @JohnSmith company property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple functions to get the possible HTML, check:

```
$decimalHTML = '&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041';
$hexHTML = '&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29';

function getDecimalHTML($str) {
    return str_replace(
        '&#',
        '',
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/\d+/',
            function($v) {
                return str_replace(';', '', implode(array_map('chr', $v)));
            }, $str
        )
    );
}

function getHexDecimalHTML($str) {
    return str_replace(
        array('&#', 'x'),
        '',
        preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?<=x)\w+/',
            function($v) {
                return str_replace(';', '', implode(array_map('hex2bin', $v)));
            },
            $str
        )
    );
}

echo getDecimalHTML($decimalHTML) . "\n";
echo getHexDecimalHTML($hexHTML);
```

Show me:

```
javascript:alert('XSS')
javascript:alert('XSS')
```

I used [chr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.chr.php) to get de char from ASCII and [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/es/function.hex2bin.php) to get the string from hexadecimal code....

I recommend not reinvent the wheel and use libraries that work for you and they cover all aspects of this problem, like [AntiXSS](https://github.com/voku/anti-xss)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.